# Can't get typeahead.js example to get to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

I'm trying out the basic example given at [typeahead.js](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/) and I can't seem to get it working. I've included the jQuery and typeahead files and they are included in the rendered page but I keep getting the error

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

on the line

`$('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({`

implying that typeahead or jquery is not loaded. None of the files 404 and they are infact loaded. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
          return function findMatches(q, cb) {
            var matches, substringRegex;

            // an array that will be populated with substring matches
            matches = [];

            // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
            substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

            // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
            // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
            $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
              if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
                // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
                matches.push({ value: str });
              }
            });

            cb(matches);
          };
        };

        var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
          'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
          'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
          'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
          'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
          'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
          'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
          'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
          'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
        ];

        $('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
          hint: true,
          highlight: true,
          minLength: 1
        },
        {
          name: 'states',
          displayKey: 'value',
          source: substringMatcher(states)
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Works good Here : http://jsfiddle.net/J6SHJ/5/

Comment: @SridharR Yeah, I know. This is a direct example from the example section. What my question is, why could I be getting that error?

Answer (score 1):

update typehead js from this link http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.10.2/typeahead.bundle.min.js

Try this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var substringMatcher = function (strs) {
        return function findMatches(q, cb) {
            var matches, substringRegex;

            // an array that will be populated with substring matches
            matches = [];

            // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
            substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

            // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
            // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
            $.each(strs, function (i, str) {
                if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                    // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
                    // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
                    matches.push({
                        value: str
                    });
                }
            });

            cb(matches);
        };
    };

    var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
        'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
        'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
        'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
        'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
        'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
        'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
        'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
        'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'];

    $('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1
    }, {
        name: 'states',
        displayKey: 'value',
        source: substringMatcher(states)
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/J6SHJ/5/)

Comment: Removing typeahead.js did not work. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Because there's a typo in the demo. See below.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/typeahead.bundle.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
              return function findMatches(q, cb) {
                var matches, substringRegex;

                // an array that will be populated with substring matches
                matches = [];

                // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`

                /* TYPO !!==> 
                substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
                 */

               substringRegex == new RegExp(q, 'i');

                // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
                // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
                $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
                  if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                    // the typeahead jQuery plugin expects suggestions to a
                    // JavaScript object, refer to typeahead docs for more info
                    matches.push({ value: str });
                  }
                });

                cb(matches);
              };
            };

            var states = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
              'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
              'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
              'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
              'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
              'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
              'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
              'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
              'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
            ];

            $('#the-basics .typeahead').typeahead({
              hint: true,
              highlight: true,
              minLength: 1
            },
            {
              name: 'states',
              displayKey: 'value',
              source: substringMatcher(states)
            });
        }); 
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Local variables must be declared with the `var` keyword or the `let` keyword.

```
substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
//to
var substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
```

Comment: Unexpectedly it was just that!